# Sample from Multivariate normal distribution using Boost

Tags: c++, boost, normal-distribution, multivariate-partition

I can sample from a normal distribution using Boost in c++.

I have now a simple question:

How can i sample from a multivariate normal distribution (n>2) using Boost functions (normal distribution, multi-arrays...) ?

Comment: I have never done this kind of thing, but [this](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/att-64979/multivariate_normal_distribution.hpp) might help...

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can simply generate the normal distribution for each axis with the given means and variants. (If the are not correlated)

Comment: what if they are correlated???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you won't be able to do this without a little bit of linear algebra. Effectively, if you have a covariance matrix C, you can generate an upper triangular matrix L using [Cholesky Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) such that C = L*L^T. This matrix L can be used now to generate a sample from the distribution with covariance C, by applying L to a vector of uncorrelated noise.